# No resource identifier found for attribute 'domain' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting the following error on running my app:

MyApp\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(38) No resource identifier found for attribute 'domain' in package 'android'.

Someone please help. Thanks in advance.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.trial.myapp">

    <!--xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:backupAgent="MyApp_BackupAgent">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
            android:value="API-KEY" />
        <!-- for backuping to google drive starts here-->
        <full-backup-content>
            <include
                android:domain="database"
                android:path=".">
            </include>
        </full-backup-content>
        <!-- for backuping to google drive ends here-->
        <activity android:name=".MyApp_MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: First thing, don't expose your API keys on a public platform.

Comment: @M.Ashish thanks for your comment..

Comment: @Darpan....Thanks for your editting.

Comment: What exactly you want to do in your app?

Comment: Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html)

Comment: @M.Ashish I am trying to create an app where I use SQLite Db to store data. And I need to backup this SQLite data to google drive. This is my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this as mentioned in this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html)

(i) In `AndroidManifest.xml`, add `android:fullBackupContent` attribute to the  element. This attribute points to an XML file that contains backup rules.

```
<application 
   ...
   android:fullBackupContent="@xml/my_backup_rules">
</application>
```

(ii) Create an XML file called `my_backup_rules.xml` in the `res/xml/` directory. Inside the file, add rules with the `<include>` and `<exclude>` elements. The following sample backs up all shared preferences except `device.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="."/>
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="device.xml"/>
</full-backup-content>
```